# OOP Problems JS

Tags: javascript, oop

I am having problems with javasript OOP. Currently, I have two short files.

player.js

```
function Player(x,y,source){
    this.hp = 100;
    this.speed = 5;
    this.posx = x;
    this.posy = y;
    this.img = new Raster({
        source: source,
        position: new Point(x,y)
    });

    this.displayPlayer();
}    
Player.prototype = {
    constructor: Player,
    displayPlayer:function(){
        this.img.position = new Point(this.posx, this.posy);
    }
};
```

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://paperjs.org/assets/js/paper.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <style>html{background-color:#DDDDDD;}</style>

        <script src="player.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="powerup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/paperscript" canvas="myCanvas">
            red = new Player(100,100,'red.png');
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="600" style="background-color:#FFFFFF !important;"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

All I get is a blank screen with nothing.

Link: http://onlyabutton.com/projects/pixelrage/

Comment: _Uncaught ReferenceError: Raster is not defined_

Comment: thanks, let me check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have some paper configuration error. All paper.js structures is hidden in paper object. So you must call it like this

```
new paper.Raster(....
```

and code is like this

```
function Player(x,y,source){
    this.hp = 100;
    this.speed = 5;
    this.posx = x;
    this.posy = y;
    this.img = new paper.Raster({
        source: source,
        position: new paper.Point(x,y)
    });

    this.displayPlayer();
}    
Player.prototype = {
    constructor: Player,
    displayPlayer:function(){
        this.img.position = new paper.Point(this.posx, this.posy);
    }
};
```

This is not a solution, this is a dirty code.

Comment: I not know the paper.js but maybe the code inside this "<script type="text/paperscript" canvas="myCanvas">" must run with paper private scope. Recheck the examples.

Answer (score 0):

`Raster` is not being defined and is giving you a ReferenceError.

Are you sure you correctly linked to/implemented Paper.js?